# Azure Data factory copy activity having time lag while triggering

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having several Copy activities in Azure Data Factory Pipeline from Azure SQL Source to Azure Data Lake Store for  different tables independent of each other.
I have scheduled it for every 15 mins. I am seeing a time lag of around 1 minute while triggering such as 12:00 AM jobs are triggering at 12:01 AM.

Also only 2 copy activities getting kick started at a time out of 20+ activities remaining getting triggered one by one .

Is this expected behavior? Any ways to eradicate this time lag?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SLA for Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/data-factory/v1_0/), Activity Runs SLA is within 4 minutes. And also a common practice is to avoid o'clock spike, especially for 12AM (UTC).